# How to filter foreign key attribute(list of) in nested Django Rest?

Tags: django, rest, filter

This is the Model, and want to implement the filter attributes are Brand, Product_type, Price(price_range). Where Brand might be more than one and price in price range(example: 2000-3000), I have tried with chain filter,

```
objects =  Tyre.objects.filter(brand__name__in=brands).filter(product_type__in=types).filter(
                tyre_price__price__range=(min_price, max_price))
```

But when any one of the attribute send empty, then the result comes empty queryset. How to implement??
Thank in advance.

```
    class Brand(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        brand_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)  

    class Tyre(models.Model):
        vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        normalsectionwidth = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
        normalaspectratio = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        constructiontype = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        rimdiamter = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
        loadindex = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        speedsymbol = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        pattern = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        warranty_summery = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        left_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        right_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        front_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        back_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        mrp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        construction_type_R = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand,models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='brand')
        brand_model = models.ForeignKey(BrandModel, models.DO_NOTHING)
        warranty_by_year = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        warranty_by_km = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class TyrePrices(models.Model):
        tyre = models.ForeignKey(Tyre, related_name='tyre_price')
        price = models.IntegerField()
        vendor = models.ForeignKey(User)
        discount = models.IntegerField()
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
        discount_price = models.IntegerField()
        stock = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='stock')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current ORM query is using AND clause at database level hence you are not getting results as per your exceptions

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Q
objects = Tyre.objects.filter(Q(brand__name__in=brands) | Q(product_type__in=types) | Q(tyre_price__price__range=(min_price, max_price)))
```

Comment: In this case it only filters the objects by only brands, this is not expected.

Comment: SELECT `tyre`.`id`, `tyre`.`vehicle`, `tyre`.`product_type`, `tyre`.`normalSectionWidth`, `tyre`.`normalAspectRatio`, `tyre`.`constructionType`, `tyre`.`rimDiamter`, `tyre`.`leadIndex`, `tyre`.`speedSymbol`, `tyre`.`category`, `tyre`.`pattern`, `tyre`.`description`, `tyre`.`warranty_summery`, `tyre`.`left_image`, `tyre`.`name`, `tyre`.`right_image`, `tyre`.`front_image`, `tyre`.`back_image`, `tyre`.`mrp`, `tyre`.`construction_type_R`, `tyre`.`brand`, `tyre`.`brand_model`, `tyre`.`warranty_by_year`, `tyre`.`warranty_by_km` (continue)

Comment: FROM `tyre` INNER JOIN `brand` ON (`tyre`.`brand` = `brand`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tyre_prices` ON (`tyre`.`id` = `tyre_prices`.`tyre_id`) WHERE (`brand`.`name` IN (appolo, MRF) OR `tyre`.`product_type` IN (PSR, Tubed) OR `tyre_prices`.`price` BETWEEN 1000 AND 8000)